# BIML Dataflow fails to read Configuration file

Tags: ssis, dataflow, biml

**Summary**

Configuration file lookup works for Execute SQL Task, but fails for Dataflow tasks.

**Problem**

I have 2 databases:

1. Source (On-premise SQL Server database)
2. Destination (Azure SQL Database)

I have 2 packages that I want to create from BIML code.

1) Create Staging (Works fine)

- Creates tables in destination database using for each loop and metadata from source database

2) Load Staging (Does not work)

- Loads created tables in destination database using for each loop and Dataflow tasks (Source to Destination)

Both of these packages need to use a Package Configuration file that I have created, which stores the Username and Password of the Destination database (Azure database, using SQL Server Authentication).

Using this configuration file works fine for Package 1), but when I try to create the SSIS package using BIML code for Package 2) I get the following error:

```
Could not execute Query on Connection Dest: SELECT * FROM stg.SalesTaxRate. Login failed for user ''.
```

I have tried using the BIML Code for Package 1) and adding in a dataflow task and that seems to raise the same error - it seems that when using an Execute SQL Task it can find and use the Configuration file no problem, but when using a Dataflow Task it won't find it.

Script for Package 1):

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ template language="C#" tier="2" #>
<#
    string _source_con_string = @"Data Source=YRK-L-101098;Persist Security Info=true;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2016";
    string _dest_con_string = @"Data Source=mpl.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=mpldb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False";

    string _table_name_sql = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'"; 

    DataTable _table_names = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter _table_name_da = new SqlDataAdapter(_table_name_sql, _source_con_string);
    _table_name_da.Fill(_table_names);  

#>
<#+ 
public string RowConversion(DataRow Row)
{
    string _ret = "[" + Row["COLUMN_NAME"] + "] " + Row["DATA_TYPE"];


    switch (Row["DATA_TYPE"].ToString().ToUpper())
    {
        case "NVARCHAR":
        case "VARCHAR":
        case "NCHAR":
        case "CHAR":
        case "BINARY":
        case "VARBINARY":
            if (Row["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"].ToString() == "-1")
                _ret += "(max)";
            else
                _ret += "(" + Row["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"] + ")";
            break;

        case "NUMERIC":
            _ret += "(" + Row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"] + "," + Row["NUMERIC_SCALE"] + ")";
            break;

        case "FLOAT":
            _ret += "(" + Row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"] + ")";
            break;
    }

    return _ret;
}
#> 

<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Connections>
    <OleDbConnection Name="Dest" ConnectionString="Data Source=mpl.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=mpldb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False" /> 
  </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="005_Create_Staging_Configuration" ConstraintMode="Linear">

            <PackageConfigurations>
                <PackageConfiguration Name="Configuration">
                    <ExternalFileInput ExternalFilePath="C:\VSRepo\BIML\Configurations\AzureConfigEdit.dtsConfig">
                    </ExternalFileInput>
                </PackageConfiguration>
            </PackageConfigurations>

            <Tasks>
            <Container Name="Create Staging Tables" ConstraintMode="Linear">
                <Tasks>
                    <# foreach(DataRow _table in _table_names.Rows) {    #>           
                    <ExecuteSQL Name="SQL-S_<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>" ConnectionName="Dest">
                        <DirectInput>

                            IF OBJECT_ID('stg.<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>','U') IS NOT NULL
                            DROP TABLE stg.<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>;

                            CREATE TABLE stg.<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>
                            (
                            <#

                                string _col_name_sql = "select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE,  CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA='" + _table["TABLE_SCHEMA"] + "' and TABLE_NAME='"+ _table["TABLE_NAME"] + "' order by ORDINAL_POSITION ";

                                DataTable _col_names = new DataTable();
                                SqlDataAdapter _col_names_da = new SqlDataAdapter(_col_name_sql, _source_con_string);
                                _col_names_da.Fill(_col_names);

                                for (int _i=0; _i<_col_names.Rows.Count ; _i++  )
                                {
                                    DataRow _r = _col_names.Rows[_i];

                                    if (_i == 0)
                                        WriteLine(RowConversion(_r));
                                    else
                                        WriteLine(", " + RowConversion(_r));                                
                                }

                            #>
                            , append_dt datetime
                            )
                        </DirectInput>
                    </ExecuteSQL>
                    <# } #>
                </Tasks>
            </Container>
            </Tasks>        
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Script for Package 2)

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ template language="C#" tier="2" #>
<#
    string _source_con_string = @"Data Source=YRK-L-101098;Persist Security Info=true;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2016";
    string _dest_con_string = @"Data Source=mpl.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=mpldb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False";

    string _table_name_sql = "select  TABLE_SCHEMA , table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'"; 

    DataTable _table_names = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter _table_name_da = new SqlDataAdapter(_table_name_sql, _source_con_string);
    _table_name_da.Fill(_table_names);  

#>

<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Connections>
    <OleDbConnection Name="Source" ConnectionString="Data Source=YRK-L-101098;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=true;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2016" />
    <OleDbConnection Name="Dest" ConnectionString="Data Source=mpl.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=mpldb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False" />
  </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="006_Load_Staging_Configuration" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <PackageConfigurations>
                <PackageConfiguration Name="Configuration">
                    <ExternalFileInput ExternalFilePath="C:\VSRepo\BIML\Configurations\AzureConfigDF.dtsConfig"></ExternalFileInput>
                </PackageConfiguration>
            </PackageConfigurations>
            <Tasks>
            <Container Name="Load Staging Tables" ConstraintMode="Linear">
                <Tasks>
                    <# foreach(DataRow _table in _table_names.Rows) {    #>     
                    <Dataflow Name="DFT-S_<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>">
                        <Transformations>
                            <OleDbSource Name="SRC-<#= _table["TABLE_SCHEMA"] #>_<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>" ConnectionName="Source">
                                <DirectInput>
                                    SELECT  *
                                    FROM <#= _table["TABLE_SCHEMA"] #>.<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>
                                </DirectInput>
                            </OleDbSource>
                            <OleDbDestination Name="DST-<#= _table["TABLE_SCHEMA"] #>_<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>" ConnectionName="Dest">
                                <ExternalTableOutput Table="stg.<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>"/>
                            </OleDbDestination>
                        </Transformations>
                    </Dataflow>
                    <# } #>
                </Tasks>
            </Container>
            </Tasks>        
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Source].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>"Data Source=YRK-L-101098;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=true;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2016"</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Dest].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=mpl.database.windows.net;User ID=*****;Initial Catalog=mpldb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Dest].Properties[Password]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>******</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Dest].Properties[UserName]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>******</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

**Note**: Values for 'UserId' and 'Password' are filled with correct values in actual script.

Comment: Good question - I'll see if I can enlist the Biml hivemind on this. One thing to try is wrap your destination ExternalTable with braces `Table="[stg].[<#= _table["TABLE_NAME"] #>]"` I've run into scenarios somewhere along the way where that mattered

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for reply. The tables read fine - it's more of an issue in failing to use the config file upon package creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**
The issue is that you are trying to use package configurations (an SSIS run-time feature) when developing the packages by generating them using Biml (a build-time feature).

**What is happening?**
Think of it this way. If you were to manually create the SSIS package, during development, you would have to connect to the source and destination databases by specifying user names and passwords. Without connecting to the databases, SSIS will not be able to get the metadata needed. Once the package has been developed and all the metadata has been mapped, you can use package configurations. When you open or execute a package with package configurations, all hardcoded values will be replaced by configuration values. This value replacement is the SSIS run-time feature.

Now, compare that to using Biml instead of manually creating the SSIS package: When generating the packages, you are expecting the Biml engine to get the user names and passwords from the package configuration files. Since this is an SSIS run-time feature, Biml is unable to get that data, and will use the connection strings specified in the BimlScript. Since these connection strings don't specify the user names and passwords, Biml will not be able to connect and you get the error *Login failed for user ''*. (This is similar to creating a connection manager in SSIS without providing a user name and password and getting an error when clicking "Test Connection".)

**But it works for the Execute SQL task?**
It may look like it, but it doesn't. The Execute SQL task basically just gets ignored. The SQL code in Execute SQL tasks is not checked or validated by SSIS or the Biml engine until the package is executed. You can type anything in there, and SSIS will be happy until you try to execute invalid code, at which point it will give you an error. Because this code is not validated by SSIS during development, it is not validated by Biml during package generation. The package gets generated successfully, and then when you open it, the package configurations will be applied, and you will not see any errors.

An OLE DB Destination, however, is validated by both SSIS and the Biml engine during development. They both need to connect to the database to get the metadata. This is why you get an error on this file only.

**Solution**
Package Configurations are an SSIS run-time feature only. You can not use them to pass connection strings, user names or passwords to the Biml engine. You can either hardcode the connection strings in your BimlScript or store the connection strings in an external metadata repository, but you will need to provide the user names and passwords to the Biml engine during package generation.

Comment: I always think the best answers are those that make you feel stupid afterwards - thanks for such a clearly explained answer!